# libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /opt/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/bin/cmake)

Tags: arch-linux, openssl, android, cmake

I met this problem only with Android-studio, system cmake works fine.

```
/opt/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/bin/cmake: /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /opt/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/bin/cmake)
/opt/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/bin/cmake: /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /opt/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/bin/cmake)
/opt/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/bin/cmake: /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /opt/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/bin/cmake)
```

I have run with duckduck and googled but did not found proper solution. How to fix these?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No. But i know a way: *use the system CMake with setting toolchain and modules path*

Comment: My problem was similar, but not exactly the same. So I think it might be worth linking to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43623089/openssl-1-0-0-not-found-on-antergos-linux/43651790#43651790

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with old CMake bundled into Android Studio. It refers to an old libssl.
Idea 1. Downgrade libssl
Idea 2. Use system Cmake cross-complilation. https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Cross_Compiling

Todo: describe solutions in details.